# How to delete existing directory - RUBY installfest creating app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Starting out with *Ruby on Rails Installfest* where it has me create and deploy an app. Ran into an issue when trying to deploy the app so wanted to go back and start over, however when prompted to create directory:

```
mkdir railsbridge
```

I get

```
mkdir: railsbridge: File exists
```

How can I remove this existing directory to start over completely?

Answer (score 1):

If your `railsbridge` folder isn't empty, then `rmdir` isn't going to work. Instead, you can try `rm -rf railsbridge` to force removing directories and their contents recursively.

References:

`rmdir` - http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rmdir

`rm -rf` - http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=rm+-rf